# How to stop a faux leather jacket from squeaking?

Tags: clothing, sound

I recently bought a new jacket, I thought it was leather but alas, turns out to be a plastic alternative (I believe it to be polyethylene). Anyway, when I wear the jacket, it is quite squeaky, especially whenever I move my arms or wear a backpack.

Does anyone know of anything I could put on the jacket to prevent this occurring - some sort of coating rather than actual modifications would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [silicone gease](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone_grease?wprov=sfla1).

Specially since baby powder may not be an option depending on the color of your jacket.

There are several products and very low cost alternatives that can be used *"off label"* for his purpose.

**Thermal paste** for your overclocked gaming rig: nothing but *silicone grease*.

Seen that greasy thing they use for soldering? **Soldering flux** is the some same stuff as the CPU thermal paste: *silicon grease*. Borrow some from school's electronics lab. (You may find yourself suddenly very popular among the electronics enthusiast crowd, though ;) )

Most pastes are odorless, although you can find scented *and even flavored!* alternatives at your local mall's sex shop, where they sell the stuff as **Silicon based lubricant** (it's the *non-water based* lubricant that won't dissolve condoms) this is a good investment, I doubt any of it will go to waste.

Also, you can find the stuff as "***Rubber seal lubricant***" at the hardware store. Comes in two varieties: automotive (for door/window/sunroof rubber seals ) or residential: ( lubricant for rubber door seals).

A blob the roughly the size of a cashew should be more than plenty for coating the most squeaky parts of your jacket, and then some.

*Slicon grease* won't swell, corrode or dissolve your jacket as using petroleum jelly or some other Vaseline based ointments will do.

---

***WD-40*** would do the trick too as one of it's [many uses](https://wd40.com/uses-tips) is as a rubber lubricant, but odor may be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try sprinkling baby powder on the jacket, and then wiping with a wet cloth. Try to find unscented powder to prevent the smell!

Answer (score 0):

Use little bit of petrolium jelly / Vaseline

Comment: Could you please explain how you would use this.  That would make a much better answer.